# Sharepoint 2013 PickerTreeView change font color

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

On my Sharepoint 2013 site, our current background clashes with the font color in the PickerTree (upload document -> choose folder). I'm not allowed to change the background, nor the theme (company preference).

Is there a way to change the font color for this specific popup manually? I've edited pages before in Sharepoint Designer, but there is no way to open this page in Sharepoint Designer because it is a popup window. The file I need to access is `_layouts/15/PickerTreeView.aspx`, but I can't access this file.

[image: screenshot pickertreeview]

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint On-Premise, we can go to **C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS** and find the **PickerTreeView.aspx** page.

Then copy this file(backup), and open the **PickerTreeView.aspx** page using notepad, then add the CSS style below into the "**PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead**".

```
<style>
#ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_TreeView1 a{
    color:black;
}
</style>
```

If you use SharePoint Online, we can't modify this file.